# Want MultiIndex for rows and columns with read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

My .csv file looks like:

```
Area    When    Year    Month   Tickets
City    Day     2015    1       14
City    Night   2015    1       5
Rural   Day     2015    1       18
Rural   Night   2015    1       21
Suburbs Day     2015    1       15
Suburbs Night   2015    1       21
City    Day     2015    2       13
```

containing 75 rows.  I want both a row multiindex and column multiindex that looks like:

```
Area         City        Rural         Suburbs
When         Day Night   Day Night     Day Night
Year Month
2015 1       5.0   3.0  22.0  11.0    13.0   2.0
     2      22.0   8.0   4.0  16.0     6.0  18.0
     3      26.0  25.0  22.0  23.0    22.0   2.0
2016 1      20.0  25.0  39.0  14.0     3.0  10.0
     2       4.0  14.0  16.0  26.0     1.0  24.0
     3      22.0  17.0   7.0  24.0    12.0  20.0
```

I've read the .read_csv doc at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

I can get the row multiindex with:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('c:\\Data\Tickets.csv', index_col=[2, 3])
```

I've tried:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('c:\\Data\Tickets.csv', index_col=[2, 3], header=[1, 3, 5])
```

thinking [1, 3, 5] fetches 'City', 'Rural', and 'Suburbs'.  How do I get the desired column multiindex shown above?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to `pivot_table` with multiple indexes *and* multiple columns.

Start with just reading you csv plainly

```
df = pd.read_csv('Tickets.csv')
```

Then

```
df.pivot_table(index=['Year', 'Month'], columns=['Area', 'When'], values=['Tickets'])
```

With the input data you provided, you'd get

```
Area             City           Rural            Suburbs
When             Day    Night   Day     Night    Day    Night
Year    Month                       
2015    1        14.0   5.0     18.0    21.0     15.0   21.0
        2        13.0   NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you, RafaelC!